# Menu pop out with $.ajax, getting array {0}

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So, I have this click function, whenever i press one of the DIV elements, it pushes out a menu on the side, where i want to have more information about the DIV element ive clicked on.

I have been able to get the which element im clicking on.

But I can't seem to get the information out from the jQuery, to the PHP page.

All it ends up doing is getting (from console)

```
Nopearray(0) {}
```

I've been working myself blind, and can't come up with any ideas how to fix it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.placeContainer').click(function () {
        var myKey = $(this).attr('data-id');
        console.log(myKey);

// .placeContainer Element movment here // 

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'info.php',
        data: {num: myKey},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

info.php

```
$numphp = isset($_POST['num'])? json_encode($_POST['num']) : 'Nope';
echo $numphp;
```

index.php

```
<main id="mainWindow">
<div id="content">
    <?php require 'clickableobjects.php' ?>
    </div>

<!-- Object that pops out-->
<div id="messageWindow">
     <?php require 'info.php' ?>   <-- should i do it like this?
</div></div>
```

Should I require it like that, or does it need to be called on within the click function?

Answer (score 0):

First about info.php - you should not require it at all. You should be calling the php script using the $.ajax method, and I think you are doing it correct (assuming that info.php is in the same folder as your index file.

I have a few tips that might help you with your case :

1. The $.ajax() has been called from the $('.placeContainer').click function body, right? It looks like its outside from what you have posted.
2. Open the development console (F12), click tab "Console" and refresh. Are there any JS errors? Click on the divs and see if an error appears.
3. Open the development console again and click on tab "Network" and refresh again. Do you see a request in red, when clicking on the div elements (meaning the ajax has failed to connect to your php script).

If these steps are okay, then you should see a new line added to the network tab whenever you click a div. If this line is not colored in red, then your communication between JS and PHP is okay and you could display the result in the div with id="messageWindow".

You can do so on the success method of the ajax, by rewriting it like this :

```
success: function (data) {
        $("#messageWindow").html(data);
}
```

If you have any network or console errors, you should fix them first.

Comment: Thank you, helped a lot :) got one step forward!